# C# Key press Event handling

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a problem with my application.
I use customized TabControl in NeoTabControlLibrary.
and, in NeoTabPage, I have several DataGridView.

Here is the problem. In DataGridView, When I press Up/Down key, it works properly. seleceted cell moves Up/Down. But, When I press Right/Left key, event works on tabcontrol not on DataGridView.

I don't need to key navigate function on tabcontrol. I want to use key navigate on selected cell moving only.

Is there any way to fix it? Please help.

Comment: Write the code for `Form_keypress` or `Form_KeyDown` and than check inside if the tab does have Datagrid. If yes than do the left and right shift of the cells. And yes dont forget to make `Form.KeyPreview = True` in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an accurate answear it would be best if you provided some code. But while not ideal in the case you do not need Right/Left key anywhere else on the specific form you could use the

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
      //Do stuff here
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

method to specify the behaviour of those two keys.